# Detect link and return another view in react native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, hyperlink

My code:

```
const orderResultJson = [
  {
    key: 'Скачайте приложение по ссылке',
    value: 'https://google.com'
  },
  {
    key: 'Логин',
    value: 'https://instagram.com'
  },
  {
    key: 'Пароль',
    value: '849846'
  },
];

function DetailsSection({ item }){
  return(
     <View>
        <Text>{item.key}</Text>
        <Text> {replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(item.value) ? 'Cсылка' : 'No'} </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
  function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text)
    {
        var expression =  
/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi; 
        var regex = new RegExp(expression); 
        var url = text; 
        url.match(regex) ? true : false;

} 

render() {
    return (
     ........
        <FlatList
          .......
          renderItem={({item}) => <DetailsSection item={item} />} 
          keyExtractor={item => item.key} 
        />
      .....
}
```

I do have a condition inside DetailsSection function. The logic is the following:

If {item.value} contains a link, then show it "some random text"

If not, just show what is "No"

Currently, I am not fully understanding the problem. Everything seems working well, but conditional flow inside DetailsSection showing only no. But in JSON, I do have the hyperlink. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you missed the 'return' statement in replaceURLWithHTMLLinks function:

```
...
return !!url.match(regex);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the regex you are using does not allow https:// at the beginning of the URL. and also you have forgotten to return the boolean from the function. Try using this:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text)
    {
        var expression =  /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/gi; 
        var regex = new RegExp(expression); 
        var url = text; 
        return url.match(regex) ? true : false;

}
```